# Is there a way to simulate an event in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have added a click listener to all my Markers in google maps. I have added all these Markers to a MarkerCluster. I have added a click listener to this MarkerCluster. When I click on a Cluster, by default it zooms in to that area. Instead of that behavior, how do I simulate that I clicked on all the Markers inside the Cluster at the same time?

How do I simulate a click event without it happening?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by clicking all of the markers in the cluster? There might be another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use

`trigger(instance:Object, eventName:string, var_args:*)` in the `google.maps.event` namespace to tigger events.

see the reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

If you want to trigger a set of overlays at the same time, just write a loop(well, not at the same time, strictly speaking).